# Most commented / popular posts and offset

Tags: offsets, popular-posts

I am using this code to show 3 most popular posts based on number of comments :

```
<?php
            $pop_posts = 3;
                $popularposts = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title,  COUNT($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID) AS 'stammy' FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND $wpdb->posts.ID=$wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID AND post_status = 'publish' AND comment_status = 'open' GROUP BY $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID ORDER BY stammy DESC LIMIT ".$pop_posts;
                $posts = $wpdb->get_results($popularposts);
                if($posts){
                    foreach($posts as $post){
                        $post_title = stripslashes($post->post_title);
                        $guid = get_permalink($post->ID);
                        $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',false);
                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb[0], 'popular-posts-image', false);
                        $thumb = $thumb[0]; 
        ?>

                            <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" width=80 height=80 />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <h4><a href="<?php echo $guid; ?>" title="<?php echo $post_title; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h4>
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                <?php 
                        }
                }
        ?>
```

but I want to use this code in two different places, so I want to offset the first 3 posts. Is there any way I can offset the three posts?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code wrapped up in a plugin. The important thing is that it `prepare()`s the input, so the query is safe. You can define 2 arguments: Offset & Limit. Those are basically just the SQL `LIMIT`.

If you don't have any use for the plugin, just deactivate it, as it won't do anything - its output is attached to a filter …

```
$most_commented = apply_filters( 'wpse70027_display_comments', 0, 3 );
// Now process the result in your template...
```

… which can simply be put into any template file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#70027) »kaiser« Get Most Commented. 
 * Description: Just place the filter in your themes template file and you're ready to go. 
 */
function wpse70027_get_comments( $offset = 0, $limit = 10 )
{
    global $wpdb;
    static $instance;

    // Validate input
    $offset = absint( $offset );
    $limit  = absint( $limit );
    // Prevent wrong user input
    0 > $offset AND $instance['offset'] = 0;

    // Setup offset/limit as 0/10 on the 1st run
    ! isset( $instance['offset'] ) AND $instance['offset'] = $offset;
    ! isset( $instance['limit'] )  AND $instance['limit']  = $limit;
    // Setup the query string
    ! isset( $instance['query'] )  AND $instance['query']  = 
         "
            SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title,
                COUNT($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID) AS cmt
            FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->comments
            WHERE comment_approved  = '1' 
                AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID
                AND post_status     = 'publish' 
                AND comment_status  = 'open' 
            GROUP BY $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID
            ORDER BY cmt 
            DESC
            LIMIT %d, %d
         ";
    ! isset( $instance['posts'] )  AND $instance['posts']  = array();

    // Three conditions trigger a new query:
    # A) Plugin is running the first time and 'posts' isn't set
    # B) The input offset is below the default offset
    # C) The input limit is above the default limit
    if (
        ! isset( $instance['posts'] )
        OR ! in_array( $offset, range( $instance['offset'], $instance['limit'] ) )
        OR ! in_array( $limit, range( $instance['offset'], $instance['limit'] ) )
        )
    {
        // Adjust the range
        $instance['offset'] = $instance['offset'] > $offset ? $offset : $instance['offset'];
        $instance['limit']  = $instance['limit']  < $limit  ? $limit  : $instance['limit'];

        $instance['posts'] = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
             $instance['query']
            ,$instance['offset']
            ,$instance['limit']
        ) );
    }

    // Only return what was requested
    return array_intersect_key(
         $instance['posts']
        ,range( $offset, $limit )
    );
}
add_filter( 'wpse70027_display_comments', 'wpse70027_get_comments', 10, 2 );
```

*And no, there's **no difference** in performance when you put it into your functions.php file. The only thing is that this code will be gone on theme update or change, so better leave it inside a plugin.*

Comment: You could just fetch all posts at once and store posts 4—6 for the second call. Saves one query.

Comment: @toscho Right, but not exactly. It should check if the offset/limit increased/decreased. Then if should modify the `LIMIT` dynamically and only query those results that have been called in the last run. This way it could be used for dozens of calls without a real performance decrease.

Comment: Pass the total number of needed posts in the first call and the amount of returned posts in each call. Still just one query and flexible enough.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think this code does not show a thumbnail of the posts, the code I have shows thumbnail as well, is it possible to modify the above code?

Comment: also the code gives fatal error when activating it as a plugin

Comment: @JohnSmith Missing bracket: fixed. Now it _should_ also do what I wrote in the comment ↑ above.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time to correct the code, but it still does not work. it gives error in line 49 which is <code> $instance['posts'] = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(</code>

Comment: is it possible to offset the original code I posted ?  thanks again

Comment: @JohnSmith Why don't you simply use this as plugin? It's meant to be one.

Comment: @kaiser I saved it in the plugins and activate it in the plugins section but it gives me error when output it

Comment: @JohnSmith "gives me error" is no proper error description.

Comment: I am testing in local host, here is the error I get : Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in C:\Users\Home\Documents\WAMP Server\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\hello.php on line 49

Comment: here is an image : http://s16.postimage.org/3qv8sy30z/Capture.png

Comment: @JohnSmith Now we're making progress :) (image not necessary) - I just missed globalizing the `$wpdb` object.

Comment: @kaiser thanks for quick response, it doesnt show any error now but it does not output anything

Comment: @JohnSmith Problem is that I don't have a setup to test this query - and I'm not taking the effort to do one. I did another update. Then you'll have to come back with some real debug info. Read in the Codex about debugging WP, then on php.net on how to debug PHP output. The point is that you need to show me what you're getting back as result in different runs - right after the query was made. If you can't do that, then we're at the end here.

Comment: @kaiser thanks again for the modification, it just does not show anything, just blank. The code I mentioned in the first post works great, it shows thumbnail and title. Is it possible to use the same code but it have it to show the next 3 posts?

Comment: blank = no debug info. As I wrote: Read in Code on how to add debug output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wordpress query to have multiple loops in one page and offset the count in the second loop.

```
<?php 
                     $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'orderby' => 'comment_count'
                        );

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

     //Put what you want to output here

    <?php 

        endwhile; 

        endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Then you just offset it in the second query.

```
<?php 

                   $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                        'offset'  => 3
                        );

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );



  ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

     //Put what you want to output here

    <?php 

        endwhile; 

        endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters